# Custom useEffect Second Argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The new React API includes `useEffect()`, the second argument of which takes an `Object` which React diffs to see if the component updated.

e.g.

```
useEffect(
  () => {
    const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
    return () => {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  },
  [props.source],
);
```

where `[props.source]` is the argument in question.

My question is: can I define a custom function to run to check if the prop has changed?

I have a custom object and React can't seem to tell when it has changed.

Comment: Hey, yep,[here's](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-github-profile/commit/56e0019a310d060fac7fedf2ba6518fcabfbe389) a link to GitHub code to where he does a custom equality check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK it's not currently possible. There are some workarounds:

1) Do deep comparison manually inside `useEffect`. To store the prev. value you may use `useState` or, even better, `useRef` as demonstrated here: https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

2) Hashing with `JSON.stringify(props.source)`. Can be fine, if the data is not too big. Note that `stringify` may produce inconsistent results (keys in objects changing order will change the output).

3) Hashing with `md5(props.source)` (or some other quick/light hashing). More realiable yet slower than the previous.

Comment: Can you clarify the first point of manual deep comparison? I tried using a function which returned a custom comparison, but no luck.

Comment: The video is not free. Says I need to sign up, which costs $250 or $40 per month. It's not cool that answer here costs a minimum $40 to view!

Comment: @CraigV it was free when I posted the answer. They probably changed the terms. You can check LevelUp tutorials on YouTube as a free alternative. They've started a great series on hooks recently.

Comment: @CraigV also, the code is open source. You can see it [here](https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-github-profile/commit/56e0019a310d060fac7fedf2ba6518fcabfbe389).

Comment: @IvanKleshnin I don't know man, feels like solicitation to link a costly video. I would say remove the video link and just replace it with the code link. Thanks

Comment: Ok. I replaced the link. Now it's Dan's Abramov article on the same topic.

Comment: I have the same doubt as @ColinRicardo .
Can you clarify the first point of manual deep comparison? Using the `useRef`? I didn't get the idea. Way too abstract. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Credit for this answer goes to @Tholle
[use object in useEffect 2nd param without having to stringify it to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808749/use-object-in-useeffect-2nd-param-without-having-to-stringify-it-to-json/55808960?noredirect=1#comment98705815_55808960)

```js
const { useState, useEffect, useRef } = React;
const { isEqual } = _;

function useDeepEffect(fn, deps) {
  const isFirst = useRef(true);
  const prevDeps = useRef(deps);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isSame = prevDeps.current.every((obj, index) =>
      isEqual(obj, deps[index])
    );

    if (isFirst.current || !isSame) {
      fn();
    }

    isFirst.current = false;
    prevDeps.current = deps;
  }, deps);
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ foo: "foo" });

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setState({ foo: "foo" }), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => setState({ foo: "bar" }), 2000);
  }, []);

  useDeepEffect(() => {
    console.log("State changed!");
  }, [state]);

  return <div>{JSON.stringify(state)}</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Why use `useRef` instead of `useState`

By using the function returned from useState the component will be re-rendered, which is not desired in this case

Answer (score 1):

Taking inspiration from other answers, I've been using the following hook

```
import React from 'react';

import IsEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

/**
 * The role of this function is to ensure that useEffect doesn't not
 * fire unless the value of a varr (variable but "var" is a reserved word )
 * changes. For examples:
 * const a = { 'hi': 5 }
 * const b = { 'hi': 5 }
 *
 * a === b // false
 * IsEqual(a, b) // true
 *
 * By default the React.useEffect(() => {}, [dependencies]) only does "===" but
 * for cases where we only want useEffect to re-fire when the true value
 * of a varr changes "IsEqual", we use this.
 *
 * @param varr: any
 * @returns {function(): *}
 */
const useMostRecentImmutableValue = (varr) => {
  let mostRecentValue = varr;
  const mostRecentPointer = React.useRef(varr);

  return () => {
    // short circuit if "shallow equality"
    if (mostRecentPointer.current === varr) {
      return mostRecentValue;
    }

    // mostRecentValue only updates when the true value of varr changes
    if (!IsEqual(varr, mostRecentPointer.current)) {
      mostRecentValue = varr;
    }

    // mostRecentPointer changes every time "shallow equality" fails but
    // after we've checked deep equality
    mostRecentPointer.current = varr;

    return mostRecentValue;
  };
};

export default useMostRecentImmutableValue;
```

And then in a hook I would do something like this:

```
import useMostRecentImmutableValue from 'use-most-recent-immutable-value.hook';

const useMyHook = (foo = { 'hi': 5 }) => {
  const mostRecentFoo = useMostRecentImmutableValue(foo);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = mySubscriptionFunction(mostRecentFoo);
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, [mostRecentFoo]);

};

export default useMyHook;
```