# React - useEffect running even when there was no change in state variable

Tags: reactjs, jwt, fetch, react-devtools

I have an endpoint in my kotlin app that looks like this:

```
    either.eager<String, Unit> {
      val sessionAndCookieUser = commonAuth.decryptCookieGetUser(getCookie(context), ::userTransform).bind()
      val user = sessionAndCookieUser.session.user
      val ctx = Ctx(ds, SystemSession, conf)
      val dbUser = getUserEither(ctx, user.id).bind()

      val signatureAlgorithm = SignatureAlgorithm.HS256
      val signingKey = SecretKeySpec(conf.get(ZendeskJWTSecret).toByteArray(), signatureAlgorithm.jcaName)

      val iat = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
      val exp = Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)

      val token = Jwts.builder()
          .claim("name", dbUser.name)
          .claim("email", dbUser.email)
          .setIssuer(conf.get(StreamAppName))
          .setIssuedAt(iat)
          .setExpiration(exp)
          .signWith(signingKey, signatureAlgorithm)
          .compact()

      context.setResponseCode(StatusCode.OK)
          .setResponseType("application/json")
          .send(jsonObject("token" to token).toString())
    }.mapLeft {
      context.setResponseCode(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED)
    }
```

I am setting a response where I should send a `jsonObject` if a user is authenticated or `UNAUTHORIZED` if the user is not authenticated.
When I am testing this endpoint in a browser I just get `status unknown` for that request - when I was debugging the backend, otherwise I get `200` with no response data.
If I test it in postman I get json as a response.
I see that token is being built and everything looks good on the backend side, but then response is not being loaded in the browser.

I am fetching it like this from react:

```
export const fetchGet = (uriPath: string) => 
  fetch(fullUrl(uriPath), {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
})

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('got here')
    fetchGet('/auth/token')
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res ', res)
       return res.json()
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('res.json ', res)
        return res.ok ? setJwtToken(res.token) : Promise.reject(res.statusText)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('err ', error)
        setError(error.toString())
      })
  }, [])
```

In the console I can only see 'got here' being logged, nothing else,  and frontend crushed with an error:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64, longTokenString...:
> Load canceled due to reload of inspected page

What am I doing wrong here?

**Updated**

I found an issue here, I had 2 more `useEffect` functions, and they were redirecting before I had a result. I am not sure why was the `useEffect` function where I am passing the error state variable running when there was no change from initial state?

Here is the full code:

```
const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState(null)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
    fetchGet('/auth/token')
      .then(async res => {
        const data = await res.json()
        if (!res.ok) {
          const error = data?.message || res.statusText
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }
        return data
      })
      .then(({token}) => setJwtToken(token))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err ', err)
        setError(err.toString())
      })
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (jwtToken) {
      // window.location.href = `/mypage.com?access/jwt?jwt=${jwtToken}&return_to=`
      console.log(jwtToken)
    }
  }, [jwtToken])
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(error)
    //window.location.href = '/login'
  }, [error])
```

Update nr. 2:

```
const [jwtToken, setJwtToken] = useState('')
  const { search } = useLocation()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchGet('/auth/token')
      .then(async res => {
        const data = await res.json()
        if (!res.ok) {
          const error = data?.message || res.statusText
          return Promise.reject(error)
        }
        return data
      })
      .then(({token}) => setJwtToken(token))
      .catch(() => window.location.href = '/login')
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(search)
    const returnTo = params.get('return_to') ? `&return_to=${params.get('return_to')}` : ''
    jwtToken !== '' ? window.location.href = `${url}/jwt?jwt=${jwtToken}${returnTo}` : null
  }, [jwtToken])

  return <p>Authenticating ...</p>
```

I have removed unnecessary error useEffect function, but now I get:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

I get this warning and it is also not redirecting after the token is fetched. What am I doing wrong this time around?

Comment: Can you `console.log(fullUrl(uriPath))` and report the result ... and/or show `fullUrl`'s code?

Comment: What are you seeing in the console and network tabs after commenting out the redirects from your other useEffects?

Comment: Please notice `error` is an object and that will make code inside `useEffect` loop forever because it uses the shallow comparison.

Comment: how can I avoid that? @ShinaBR2

Comment: @Leff you should remove that `useEffect`, and should handle redirect in your `.catch(err => {})` instead.

Comment: @ShinaBR2 I have done some changes based on your suggestion, you can see it under new update in the question, but now I get a new warning and it fails to redirect after it fetches token

Comment: What library are you using to fetch? I remember trying to use the fetch API and `catch` not working, however don't quote me on that. I would try to check if something has errored in `then` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my completed answer. The main problem here is using `useEffect` incorrectly, especially with objects in the dependency array.

Let's talk about this code first

```
useEffect(() => {
  // TODO something with error
}, [error]);
```

Because `error` is an object and React `useEffect` use shallow comparison as you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects). It will make the code inside that `useEffect` will run forever.

Next part, you get warnings because your use of redirect is not in the right way. Just remove that `useEffect` and it should work.

The reason why is, when we have an error, your code in your `catch` should run. Beside that, `jwtToken` will be changed at that time too. It will make your app redirected before the rendering process is completed.

Comment: I get that error useEffect was wrong, but why is the other where we set the token? If everything goes well when fetching, shouldn't that useEffect redirect normally?

Comment: @Leff because your logic to redirect and your logic inside `catch` are the same. You only need to handle only one time.

Comment: Catch happens only if there is an error and redirects to a different place, while useEffect with token should happen only if token is changed and redirect to another place, so I am not sure what do you mean by same logic?

Comment: Your `useEffect` will change whenever `jwtToken` changed is correct. But the thing is, you handle redirect in that `useEffect` also, that will make the app redirect **before** it finish re-render. That cause the warnings you get. The same logic I mean is "redirect whenever we get error". You can choose handle it either inside `catch` or inside `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1):

Every useEffect callback will be invoked on first mount. You should include a simple if statement to ensure an error is set before running your error handling logic.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if(error) {
      console.log(error)
      //window.location.href = '/login'
    }
  }, [error])
```

There is likely an issue with the CORS configuration of your API.

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header must be set to the origin of your react app (it cannot be `*` for credentialed requests) and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` must be `true`. Failing to include them will result in an opaque response.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol-and-credentials