# Infinite re-render in functional react component

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios, infinite-loop, use-effect

I am trying to set the state of a variable "workspace", but when I console log the data I get an infinite loop. I am calling the axios "get" function inside of useEffect(), and console logging outside of this loop, so I don't know what is triggering all the re-renders. I have not found an answer to my specific problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171206/infinite-console-logging-in-react-js-component). Here's my code:

```
function WorkspaceDynamic({ match }) {
  const [proposals, setProposals] = useState([{}]);
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  });

  const getItems = async () => {
    const proposalsList = await axios.get(
      "http://localhost:5000/api/proposals"
    );
    setProposals(proposalsList.data);
  };

  const [workspace, setWorkspace] = useState({});
  function findWorkspace() {
    proposals.map((workspace) => {
      if (workspace._id === match.params.id) {
        setWorkspace(workspace);
      }
    });
  }
```

Does anyone see what might be causing the re-render? Thanks!

Comment: I think useEffect causing the re-render, in short, add useEffect(()=> {getItems(); }, [getItem] ); instead of your construction with useEffect. In details, you can try to read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070970/infinite-loop-in-useeffect or https://medium.com/@andrewmyint/infinite-loop-inside-useeffect-react-hooks-6748de62871

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect hook runs every render cycle, and one without a dependency array will execute its callback every render cycle. If the effect callback updates state, i.e. `proposals`, then another render cycle is enqueued, thus creating render looping.

If you want to only run effect once when the component mounts then use an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getItems();
}, []);
```

If you want it to only run at certain time, like if the match param updates, then include a dependency in the array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  getItems();
}, [match]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your use of `useEffect` is not correct. If you do not include a dependency array, it gets called every time the component renders. As a result your `useEffect` is called which causes `setProposals` then it again causes `useEffect` to run and so on

try this

```
useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  } , []);   // an empty array means it will be called once only
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the following: `useEffect` should have a second param `[]` to make sure it's executed only once. that is:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();
  }, []);
```

otherwise `setProposal` will modify the state which will trigger a re-render, which will call `useEffect`, which will make the async call, which will `setProposal`, ...