# State doesn't change inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to use websocket with hooks and starting it on useEffect. But the states is always the initial for the websocket.

I know that it happens because useEffect creates a closure, but I didn't find a workaround.

I simplified my code to make easily understandable.
I need to make decisions according to activeContracts, but it doesn't change.
I tried not to use ws as a state, but then it is lost on new renderings.

```
function Bitstamp() {
    const [activeContracts, setActiveContracts] = useState(["btcusd"]);
    const [ws, setWs] = useState();

    useEffect(
        () => {
            let newWs = new WebSocket("wss://ws.bitstamp.net");

            newWs.onopen = function () {
                activeContracts.map(contract => newWs.send({
                    "event": "bts:subscribe",
                    "data": {
                        "channel": "order_book_btcusd"
                    }
                }));
            };

            newWs.onmessage = function (evt) {
                console.log(activeContracts);
            };

            setWs(newWs);
        },
        [],
    );

    const handleContractChange = val => {
        setActiveContracts(val);
    };

    return (
        <ToggleButtonGroup vertical type="checkbox" value={activeContracts}
                           onChange={handleContractChange}>
            <ToggleButton
                value="btcusd">"btcusd"</ToggleButton>
            )}
            <ToggleButton
                value="btceur">"btceur"</ToggleButton>
            )}
        </ToggleButtonGroup>
    );
}
```

Is there anyway to the websocket notice changes on states?
Should I initialize the websocket in another way or don't keep it as an state?

Update:

I added a useEffect tracking activeContracts and update onopen and onmessage and worked. Something like this:

```
useEffect(
    () => {
        setWs(ws => {
            ws.onopen = function () {
                activeContracts.map(contract => newWs.send({
                    "event": "bts:subscribe",
                    "data": {
                        "channel": "order_book_btcusd"
                    }
                }));
            };

            ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                console.log(activeContracts);
            };

            return ws;
        })
    },
    [activeContracts],
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `useState` runs only once when component initialises, due to the array argument being empty. You need to track `activeContracts` in that array, but because `activeContracts` is array itself you'll need to use some kind of deep compare function for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096391/4468021

Comment: why deep compare, isn't activeContracts immutable?

Comment: because arrays are compared by reference, so the callback inside `useEffect` will run on every render.

Comment: But track activeContracts would initialize the websocket again.
Maybe I could create another useState tracking activeContracts and update only newWs.onmessage on ws and setWs again.

Comment: In that case you can initialize websoket outside of use effect on only modify its `onopen` and `onmessage` inside `useEffect`.

Comment: As I need start the ws after render, i think it's better initialize on useEffect and create another useEffect to update.
Also, I dont't need to check if the values inside the array is the same, so a simple compare is ok.