# Convert <Class Component> to <Stateless Functional Component> using Hooks with a callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-tsx, react-jsonschema-forms

I am trying to convert `Class Component` to `Stateless Functional Component` using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) concept

I am working with `react-jsonschema-form` - `Custom field components` [reference link](https://react-jsonschema-form.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-customization/#custom-field-components)

```
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  required: ["lat", "lon"],
  properties: {
    lat: {type: "number"},
    lon: {type: "number"}
  }
};

// Define a custom component for handling the root position object
class GeoPosition extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {...props.formData};
  }

  onChange(name) {
    return (event) => {
      this.setState({
        [name]: parseFloat(event.target.value)
      }, () => this.props.onChange(this.state));
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {lat, lon} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="number" value={lat} onChange={this.onChange("lat")} />
        <input type="number" value={lon} onChange={this.onChange("lon")} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Define the custom field component to use for the root object
const uiSchema = {"ui:field": "geo"};

// Define the custom field components to register; here our "geo"
// custom field component
const fields = {geo: GeoPosition};

// Render the form with all the properties we just defined passed
// as props
render((
  <Form
    schema={schema}
    uiSchema={uiSchema}
    fields={fields} />
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

I am converting the above code like this.

```
function GeoPosition(props) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({ ...props.formData });

  const onChange = name => {
    return event => {
      setState(
        {
          [name]: parseFloat(event.target.value)
        },
        () => props.onChange(state) // GETTING ERROR - UNABLE TO USE CALLBACK
      );
    };
  };

  const { lat, lon } = state;
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" value={lat} onChange={onChange("lat")} />
      <input type="number" value={lon} onChange={onChange("lon")} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It throws an error, I think, I need to use React.useEffect(), but don't how to implement it. kindly any react experts support.

> index.js:1375 Warning: State updates from the useState() and
>   useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To
>   execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component
>   body with useEffect().

Comment: In your case it would be `React.useEffect(func, [state])`, indicating to call `func` when `state` changes

Answer (score 0):

The setter function from `useState` does not accept a second argument: [[hooks] useState - "setState" callback](https://github.com/reactjs/rfcs/issues/98). I'm not sure you need to use `useEffect` here, you can just call `props.onChange(state)` after setting the state values. Also note that you need to concat the existing state with the new state values because `setState` will overwrite existing state.

```
const onChange = name => {
    return event => {
      setState(state => {
          ...state,
          [name]: parseFloat(event.target.value)
        })
       props.onChange(state);
    };
  };
```

If you really need to make sure `props.onChange` is called only after the new value has been set on the current component's state, you can track the state in useEffect, altho you'll need to use a custom function for deep comparison: [react useEffect comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54096391/4468021)

```
useEffect(() => {
   props.onChange(state);
}, [deepCompare(state)])
```