# Infinite loop in useEffect if I pass object as dependency

Tags: reactjs

I have an this piece of code in my React component.

I want to create new object from values of `propArray`. Like this `linter` complains that `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency data`. But if I supply `data` to the array of `useEffect` it causes the infinite loop. I assume it is because I'm updating `data` object inside `useEffect`.

What should be done in this case?

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
      if (something) {

          const newObj = {
            ...
          }

        setData({data, ...newObj})
      }
}, [something, propArray]);
```

**EDIT**

Tried wrapping JSON.stringify(data) and passing it as dependency - works the same.

Also tried `useRef`

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})
const latestData = useRef(data)

useEffect(() => {
   if (something) {

      const newObj = {
          ...
      }

      latestData.current = newObj
   }
}, [something, propArray]);
```

But this way when I'm trying to pass `lastestData.current` as prop the component it is empty and it is not rerendering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [react useEffect comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects)

Comment: Can you create a codepen of the issue?

Comment: @ravibagul91[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-basics-z6vl3)
Comment out useEffect in Child component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another version of `setNames` using `previous state`, so that we don't need any dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (contentLoading) {
      const newNames = { a: "aa" };
      setNames(prevState => ({ ...prevState, ...newNames }));
    }
}, [contentLoading]);
```

For more on how to use `previous state` in `setState`, you can refer [this](https://itnext.io/react-setstate-usage-and-gotchas-ac10b4e03d60).

Also you can refer [When to use functional setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48209452/when-to-use-functional-setstate).

Answer (score 1):

You could write the setData as

```
    setData(d => ({d, ...newObj}))
    //or maybe you mean
    setData(d => ({...d, ...newObj}))
```

So it doesn't depend on the current value of data

edit:
fixed your sandbox with the above suggestion
https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-basics-nz0st