# How to avoid the 'Maximum update depth exceeded' warning in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, remix

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

[image]

and the source code is

```
const FilterSearch = () => {
  let filter = produtos

  if (params.searchType == "CategoriaProduto") {
    filter = produtos.filter(categoriaProduto => categoriaProduto.categoria == params.searchContent?.toString())
  }

  if (params.searchType == "Componente" && params.searchContent?.valueOf != undefined) {
    filter = produtos.filter(categoriaProduto => categoriaProduto.nome.includes(params.searchContent ? params.searchContent : ""))
  }

  return (
    filter.map(componente => {

      function getLowest() {
        if (componente.locaisVendas.length >= 1)
          return componente.locaisVendas.reduce((previous, current) => { return current.preco < previous.preco ? current : previous })
        else
          return null
      }

      const menorPreco = getLowest()

      return (
        <tr className="mt-2 my-3" key={componente.id}>
          <th className="py-3" >
            <img src="/among_us2.png" className="img-fluid" alt="Imagem responsiva" style={{ width: '100px', height: '100px', }} />
            &emsp;{componente.nome}
          </th>
          <th className="col-md-2">
            <label className="form-check-label fa fa-star text-warning" htmlFor="defaultCheck1"></label>
            <label className="form-check-label fa fa-star text-warning" htmlFor="defaultCheck1"></label>
            <label className="form-check-label fa fa-star text-warning" htmlFor="defaultCheck1"></label>
            <label className="form-check-label fa fa-star text-warning" htmlFor="defaultCheck1"></label>
            <label className="form-check-label fa fa-star text-muted" htmlFor="defaultCheck1"></label>
          </th>
          <th>R$ {menorPreco?.preco}</th>
          <th>{menorPreco?.vendedor}</th>
          <th>
            <Link to={`/Search/Product/${componente.id}`}>
              <button className="btn-details rounded p-2"><i className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-plus mx-1"></i> Ver mais detalhes</button>
            </Link>
          </th>

        </tr>
      )
    }))
}
```

I am expecting, to resolve this infinite loop

Comment: See this example for explanation and a solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57853288/react-warning-maximum-update-depth-exceeded

Comment: I can't see any effect or state hooks in your code. Are you sure this is where the error is occurring? Need to narrow it down to the exact code causing the issue.

Comment: const { slice, range } = useTable(FilterSearch(), page, 5); i using this for a pagination function, and need a array jsx.element

Comment: Based on the provided code snippet, it's not evident what could be causing the infinite loop. The issue might be occurring outside the `FilterSearch` component or in another part of your codebase