# Is there a correct way to use an object as a dependency in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-effect

I currently have a react hook that I'm creating that accepts a query object.

```js
export function useMyQuery(query: QueryObjectType)
{
    React.useEffect(executeQuery, [ query ]);
    // ...
}
```

Unfortunately, any time my hook gets called as part of a re-render, despite `query` having never changed and still being the exact same object as before, I end up with an infinite loop.

I can resolve this by wrapping `query` with `JSON.stringify(...)`, however I'm not sure if that's correct? Is there any preferred mechanism for testing equality for objects when being passed as a dependency to `useEffect`?

Comment: Can you post the component which uses `useMyQuery`?

Comment: Here is another related question that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects

Comment: @Paul - Totally picked up on what you were thinking there.  And sure enough, yeah, the object I'm passing _is_ initialized in that component.  So of course it's different every time.  Problem solved I think 

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `useState()` should help. You would need to return the setter to allow re-querying from the parent.

`useState(query)` only fires on the first render, so `_query` remains the same until explicitly set.

```js
export function useMyQuery(query: QueryObjectType)
{
    const [_query, setQuery] = useState(query);

    React.useEffect(executeQuery, [ _query ]);
    // ...

   return setQuery;
}
```