# Why this react hook cause infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

This piece of code will run infinitely, but no matter removing the `useValue(object)` or `useTest()` will stop the infinite run. This whole thing does not make sense to me, can somebody explain it?

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-currying-v2zu1?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  // this code can also stop the infinite loop

  // const [object] = useState({
  //   name: "",
  //   personId: ""
  // });
  const object = {
    name: "",
    personId: ""
  };
  // strange thing: remove useValue or useTest can stop the ifinite loop
  useValue(object);
  useTest();
  // this console will run infinitely
  console.log(object);
  return <div className="App">{"123"}</div>;
}

export const useTest = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    setA(2);
  }, []);
};

const useValue = (value) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(value);
  useEffect(() => {
    setA(value);
  }, [value]);
  // return a
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to memoize your object in order to properly use it in dependencies.

```js
const { useMemo } from 'react';

const object = useMemo(
  () => ({
    name: "",
    personId: ""
  }),
  []
);
```

The reason behind the infinite loop is because you're providing a non-memoized object into your dependency array in `useEffect`.

Object comparison in Javascript is more complex than just comparing `obj1 === obj2`, as there is a reference that needs to be taken into account.

Read more about comparing objects in javascript [here](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/comparing-objects-in-javascript-ce2dc1f3de7f)

Answer (score 1):

Because `object` is a reference type, its identity will change every time you rerender `App`.  There you use a custom hook `useValue` and pass `object` into it. Since you also register it as `value` in the dependency array of `useEffect`, `useEffect` will be triggered, setting a new state, ending in rerendering and looping.

1. Make sure, you save the identity of reference types (`useMemo` or `useCallback`).
2. Read the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) about `useEffect`. Its behaviour strongly depends on how you use its dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

Because you passed an object in the dependencies. useEffect with do a shallow comparison so it always renders.

There are some solutions. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects). You could modify your useValue hook to use JSON.stringify as below.

```
const useValue = (value) => {
    const [a, setA] = useState(value);
    useEffect(() => {
        setA(value);
    }, [JSON.stringify(value)]);
    // return a
};
```