# Real-Time graph not showing in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graph, bluetooth-lowenergy, real-time

I want to plot my data in React-Native. I am receiving data from BLE. But I can't see the real time graph on the screen. What could be the reason? My brain stopped, so I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Note : My data is,

> hr

This is BLE characteristic value.

This is my component.js,

```
const width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const height = Math.floor((Dimensions.get('window').height - 150) / 3);

let counter = 0;
const slotsPerWidth = 100;
const initialState = {
  flow: hr,
  isLoading: false,
};

class ChartScreen extends Component {
    
  state = {
    chartData: { ...initialState },
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(state) {

        counter++;
        return {
          chartData: {
            flow: [hr],
          
          },
        };
  }
  
 render() {
    const { flow} = this.state.chartData;

     return this.state.isLoading
       ? <ScreenContainer>

            <View style={styles.main}>
            <View>
                <ActivityIndicator></ActivityIndicator>
            </View>   
            <Chart
                key="flow"
                data={flow}
                maxValue={1900}
                minValue={1750}
                slotsPerWidth={slotsPerWidth}
                width={width}
                height={height}
                marginBottom={20}
                lineColor="rgba(95, 92, 1, 1)"
                lineThickness={2}
                chartBackground="#17204d"
                horizontalGridLinesCount={5}
                gridColor="rgba(65, 95, 93, .4)"
                gridThickness={1}
                unit="ml"
                axisTooClose={10}
                labelsColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)"
                labelsFontSize={12}
                marginLeft={60}
                labelsMarginLeft={15}
            />
            
            
            </View>
        </ScreenContainer>:
        null
        
    } 
}
    
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  main: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});


export default ChartScreen;
```

This is my device screen.tsx,

```
const DeviceScreen = ({
  route,
  navigation,
}: StackScreenProps<RootStackParamList, 'Device'>) => {
  // get the device object which was given through navigation params
  const { device } = route.params;
 
  const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);
  const [services, setServices] = useState<Service[]>([]);
 
  // handle the device disconnection
  const disconnectDevice = useCallback(async () => {
    navigation.goBack();
    const isDeviceConnected = await device.isConnected();
    if (isDeviceConnected) {
      await device.cancelConnection();
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    }
  }, [device, navigation]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDeviceInformations = async () => {
      // connect to the device
      const connectedDevice = await device.connect();
      
      setIsConnected(true);

   
      // discover all device services and characteristics
      const allServicesAndCharacteristics = await connectedDevice.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
      // get the services only
      const discoveredServices = await allServicesAndCharacteristics.services();
    

      setServices(discoveredServices);
  
     
       PermissionsAndroid.request(
        PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        {
          title: 'Permission Localisation Bluetooth',
          message: 'Requirement for Bluetooth',
          buttonNeutral: 'Later',
          buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          buttonPositive: 'OK',
          
        }
      );     
      };  
    getDeviceInformations();

    device.onDisconnected(() => {
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    });

    // give a callback to the useEffect to disconnect the device when we will leave the device screen
    return () => {
      disconnectDevice();
    };

    
  }, [device, disconnectDevice, navigation]);
   


  return (
    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={disconnectDevice}>
        <Text style={{fontFamily:"SairaExtraCondensedThin",textAlign:"center",fontSize:15,color:"white"}}>Antrenmanı Sonlandır</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <View style={styles.header} >
          <Text>{`Name : ${device.name}`}</Text>
          <Text>{`Is connected : ${isConnected}`}</Text>
        </View>
        {services &&
          services.map((service) => <ServiceCard service={service} />)}
      </View>
       <View>

        <ChartScreen chartdata />
       </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at least, in `component.js` the `isLoading` state is never set to `true` and in `screen.tsx` you are non passing any data since `<ChartScreen chartdata />` means `<ChartScreen chartdata={true} />`, so it is a boolean property. Then, in `getDerivedStateFromProps` you are increasing `counter` that is not part of the state, so, by itself, it will not trigger a new render. Check also that the value of `hr` is set in the proper place, looks strange to me to see it not as a part of the state too, or as a property. It needs some investigation. Also, the `useEffect` dependencies are objects so check this out, but consider to refactor the `useEffect` part, [react useEffect comparing objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects)

**Note**

Seems to me that there are some misconceptions about React here cousing most of the issues.

This may not be the actual and full answer but I decided to provide my input as a starting point for further investigation and impovements.

Comment: What change do I need to make here?

Comment: All the ones I specified in the answer and, probably, other too, as per my note. There is some misconception here I suppose.