# Async useEffect does not execute entire body when dependency changes

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to use useEffect with some async functions, however when the dependency in the dependency array changes, only the non async code gets called in useEffect.

```
    useEffect( async () => {
        console.log(account);
        const web3 = await getWeb3();
        const acc = await loadAcc(web3);
        await loadContract(web3, acc);
    }, [account])
```

When my account state variable changes, useEffect gets invoked again, but only the console.log(account) statement will get executed.

How should I work around this problem?

Answer (score 2):

The function passed into `useEffect` cannot be async. You can define an async function inside the useEffect and then use the then/catch syntax.

Further, also pass in all the functions that are defined outside of the useEffect (that you are calling) as a dependency to useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => {

  const myAsyncFunc = async () => {
     console.log(account);
     const web3 = await getWeb3();
     const acc = await loadAcc(web3);
     await loadContract(web3, acc);
  }
  myAsyncFunc.catch(console.error);
       
}, [account, getWeb3, loadAcc, loadContract])
```

Comment: Will I be able to invoke useEffect again and the function if I just leave account in the dependecy array?

Comment: Most likely it'd still work, as I wouldn't expect side effects/ any code changes from the lib functions that you are calling, but it's best practice to include all dependencies, as in the example above. You might not observe a useEffect trigger when nested fields in the account object changed (without replacing the account object). For that you could use https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect and read up on it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects

Answer (score 1):

`useEffect` expected to return either void or a function( the cleanup function ). When you make the function you pass to `useEffect` as an async, the function will return a promise.

One way to do it is,

```
    useEffect( () => {
        const init = async () => {
          const web3 = await getWeb3();
          const acc = await loadAcc(web3);
          const res = await loadContract(web3, acc);
          // do something after the async req
        }
        init();
    }, [getWeb3, loadAcc, loadContract])
```

Or else,

```
const [web3, setWeb3] = useState(null);
const [acc, setAcc] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
  getWeb3();
}, [getWeb3])

useEffect(() => {
  if (!web3) return;
  loadAcc(web3);
}, [web3, loadAcc])

useEffect(() => {
  if (acc && web3) {
   loadContract(acc, web3);
  }
}, [acc, web3, loadContract])

const getWeb3 = useCallback(async () => {
   // do some async work
   const web3 = // async call
   setWeb3(web3)
}, [])

const loadAcc = useCallback(async (web3) => {
  // do some async work
  const acc = // async call
  setAcc(acc);
}, [])

const loadContract = useCallback(async (acc, web3) {
  // do anything
}, [])
```

Comment: is the useCallback necessary?

Comment: Yes because you use those functions on dependency arrays of useEffects.