# axios.post is not sent on first attempt. But works in second try in React Native

Tags: react-native, use-effect, use-state

I am trying to make an API call on changing a state which is triggered by a toggling button in **React Native**.

For this I have used useEffect to trigger API call.

```
const GroundFloorLamps = props => {
  const [lampsState, setLampsState] = useState({
    l1: 'checked',
    l2: 'unchecked',
    l3: 'unchecked',
    l4: 'unchecked',
    l5: 'unchecked',
  });

  const sendState = async () => {
    const newState = EncodeLampState(lampsState);
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(GlobalData.azureFunctions.broadcastUrl, {
        state: newState,
      });
      Log(res.status);
    } catch (err) {
      Log('Error: \n' + err.message);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    sendState();
  }, [lampsState]);

  const onToggleSwitch = lampNo => {
    setLampsState(prev => ({
      ...prev,
      [lampNo]: prev[lampNo] === 'checked' ? 'unchecked' : 'checked',
    }));
  };
```

**But** on toggling button for the first time, it does not complete the **axios.post** (not logging the res.status). But at the second toggle it completes both API calls (axios.post). This keep happening for all the even tries and not called in all odd calls.

Please help me if anyone have an idea of this.

Answer (score 0):

React compares objects with their reference. This may affect its behavior in these cases-
1- Object is exactly the same, but compared using different references.
2- Object with different values, but compared with the same reference.

So, in your case, your lamp state is an object

```
    const [lampsState, setLampsState] = useState({
    l1: 'checked',
    l2: 'unchecked',
    l3: 'unchecked',
    l4: 'unchecked',
    l5: 'unchecked',
  });
```

there can be side effects due to it while detecting the lampstate change.

so, as to work one way , you can update your useeffect dependency array as

```
useEffect(() => {
    sendState();
  }, [lampsState.l1,lampsState.l2,lampsState.l3,lampsState.l4,lampsState.l5]);
```

or other ways you can use Memoizing of object etc,

[Refer this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects)

Comment: Great thanks for your help, **But** the problem still persist after applying your solution of dependancy array.

Comment: Interpreter comes to axios.post and not giving a response or catch any error in the **first** change of state. But gives both responses at the **second** change of state.

Comment: that's strange. You can try checking the API responses with  reactotron or flipper , to check the responses are as expected in accordance with the changes