# Excessive number of pending callbacks

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks, expo

I'm trying to arrange the data gotten from firebase but after I arrange it the app becomes slow and if I click on a button it gives an error saying "Excessive number of pending callbacks".

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chats.length && users.length) {
      const list = [];
      chats.forEach((chat) => {
        if (chat.members.includes(userId)) {
          chat.members.forEach((y) => {
            if (y !== userId) {
              console.log("receiver: " + y);
              users.forEach((z) => {
                if (z.id === y) {
                  console.log(z);
                  list.push({
                    chat: chat,
                    acc: z,
                    user: user
                  });
                }
              });
              console.log(list);
            }
          });
        }
      });

      setUserChats(list);
    }
  }, [chats, users]);
```

users and chats are both states that I got from firebase on snapshot also in useEffect

Answer (score 1):

One guess: Your dependencies don't work in the way you expect them to. `chats` and `users` aren't [primitives](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Primitive), so depending on how they get created and passed, it's possible `useEffect` is run on every render, no matter whether `chat` and `users` have changed in structure or not. So this is what might happen:

1. `useEffect()` will be called on every rerender due to your invalid dependencies.
2. `useEffect()` calls `setUserChats()` on every turn. In theory, `setUserChats()` will check whether the new state actually differs, but in the same manner as `useEffect` it "fails" in the comparison and takes every `list` as a new state.
3. `setState()` will trigger a new render. Rinse, repeat with 1)

What you need to understand it that `useEffect` checks whether dependencies have changed (and `setUserChats()` does so as well to decide whether new state actually differs from the old one). This check relies on the identity/equal reference, i.e. on `oldValue === newValue`. For non-primitive values that means: it doesn't matter if `oldValue` and `newValue` look alike or are perfect clones even - if they don't share the same address in the memory, they are taken as non-equal.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095994/react-useeffect-comparing-objects) thread or [this](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) library for solutions. In your case, a simple (but not really nice) solution would be to change your dependencies to `[JSON.stringify(chats), JSON.stringify(users)]`, but there are more elaborate, performant and reliable solutions out there.

(Additionally, you forget to add `userId` to the dependencies. So something like `[userId, JSON.stringify(chats), JSON.stringify(users)]` might be more appropriate.)

Another thought though: I don't see why all that logic requires to be put into a `useEffect()` anyway. Just calculate the `list` in the component itself and call `setUserChats(list)`. Or does it take too long?