# Infinite loop with useEffect

Tags: reactjs

Why is the following giving me an infinite rerender? I have a small component with a single `useEffect`. Does the second param `[currentData]` do shallow comparison or something ?

```
useEffect(() => {
    getMyData().then(({ data }) => {
      setData({ ...currentData }, { data });
    });
  }, [currentData]);
```

Comment: What I'm thinking is happening, is that the update to `currentData` is a trigger for the `useEffect` to run as it will execute every time `currentData` is modified (which is exactly what you are doing in the `useEffect`). Perhaps try using `[]` instead...Let me know what happens.

Comment: Yes, simply put, React uses shallow equality to determine if state and/or props have updated. This is the reason why you ***always*** return ***new*** object references when updating state. `{ ...oldState }` creates a new object reference and thus triggers a rerender and effect hook callback is triggered since dependency updated. ***Don't unconditionally update state that is part of a React hook dependency.***

Answer (score 1):

It because when you use `({...currentData})` you literally create a new object, a new reference to a new object, and Javascript compare objects by reference, not value. So the new value of `currentData` will always different from the previous once. That make the flow would look like this:

`You setData (create new Object)` => `useEffect detect that currentData changed` => `it run into the call back, subscribe again`  => `You setData (create new Object) again` => `useEffect detect that currentData changed` . And that cause the loop.

Currently, comparing deep nested object is not supported in React `useEffect`. But you can overcome the issue using a custom hook, i found another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808749/use-object-in-useeffect-2nd-param-without-having-to-stringify-it-to-json) that I think could help